# Filtered send queue in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

So I'm relatively inexperienced with rxjs so if this is something that would be a pain or really awkward to do, please tell me and I'll go a different route. So in this particular use case, I was to queue up updates to send to the server, but if there's an update "in flight" I want to only keep the latest item which will be sent when the current in flight request completes.

I am kind of at a loss of where to start honestly. It seems like this would be either a buffer type operator and/or a concat map.

Here's what I would expect to happen:

```
const updateQueue$ = new Subject<ISettings>()

function sendToServer (settings: ISettings): Observable {...}

...
// we should send this immediately because there's nothing in-flight
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 25 }); 

updateQueue$.next({ volume: 30 });
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 50 });
updateQueue$.next({ volume: 65 });

// lets assume that our our original update just completed
// I would now expect a new request to go out with `{ volume: 65 }` and the previous two to be ignored.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want with this:

```js
const allowNext$ = new Subject<boolean>()
const updateQueue$ = new Subject<ISettings>()

function sendToServer (settings: ISettings): Observable { ... }

updateQueue$
  .pipe(
    // Pass along flag to mark the first emitted value
    map((value, index) => {
      const isFirstValue = index === 0
      return { value, isFirstValue }
    }),

    // Allow the first value through immediately
    // Debounce the rest until subject emits
    debounce(({ isFirstValue }) => isFirstValue ? of(true) : allowNext$),

    // Send network request
    switchMap(({ value }) => sendToServer(value)),

    // Push to subject to allow next debounced value through
    tap(() => allowNext$.next(true))
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    ...
  })
```

Comment: This is quite a clever solution, thank you. I created a stackblitz based on this answer. Attached if you're interested. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vgd9mq?devtoolsheight=60

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty interesting question.

If you did not have the requirement of issuing the last in the queue, but simply ignoring all requests of update until the one on the fly completes, than you would simply have to use `exhaustMap` operator.

But the fact that you want to ignore all BUT the last request for update makes the potential solution a bit more complex.

If I understand the problem well, I would proceed as follows.

First of all I would define 2 Subjects, one that emits the values for the update operation (i.e. the one you have already defined) and one dedicated to emit only the last one in the queue if there is one.

The code would look like this

```
let lastUpdate: ISettings;

const _updateQueue$ = new Subject<ISettings>();
const updateQueue$ = _updateQueue$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(tap(settings => (lastUpdate = settings)));

const _lastUpdate$ = new Subject<ISettings>();
const lastUpdate$ = _lastUpdate$.asObservable().pipe(
  tap(() => (lastUpdate = null)),
  delay(0)
);
```

Then I would merge the 2 Observables to obtain the stream you are looking for, like this

```
merge(updateQueue$, lastUpdate$)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(settings => sendToServer(settings))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: res => {
      // do something with the response
      if (lastUpdate) {
        // emit only if there is a new "last one" in the queue
        _lastUpdate$.next(lastUpdate);
      }
    },
  });
```

You may notice that the variable `lastUpdate` is used to control that the last update in the queue is used only once.